# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent in cron job magento2

Tags: magento2, cron

I have a cron job in magento 2, since I have added dependencies it has stopped running. I am getting the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access parent:: when current class
> scope has no parent

and this is when I add this to the constructor :

> parent::__construct($context,$data);

If I remove this line then the cron fails because it can't see the dependencies. This is my cron, I want to log the customer ids for that store:

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class reinitpricing {

  private $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $resourceConnection;
    protected $authSession;
    private $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $helperData;
    protected $coreRegistry;
    private $currentStore;
    private $storeManager;
    private $storeId;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $_productAttributeRepository;
    private $storeResolver;
    protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
    JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory, 
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection, 
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
     \FlavourWarehouse\Pricing\Helper\Data $helperData, 
     Registry $coreRegistry,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository,
       ProductRepository $productRepository, 
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver $storeResolver, 
       \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, 
       CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->currentStore = 1;
        $this->storeId = 1;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
        $this->storeResolver = $storeResolver;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        

    }

  public function execute() {


    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logger.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("the cron job is running");

        $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
            ->addStoreFilter(1)
            ->load();

            foreach ($collection AS $customer) {
                $logger->info($customer->getId());
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because given `class reinitpricing {` have not `extends SomeClassName` because constructor tries to construct with `$context` and `$data` something from parent class.

---

Alternatively, based on `execute` method code I can suggest following.

**File: Vendor/Module/Cron/Reinitpricing.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;
class Reinitpricing {

    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory,
    )
    {  
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/logger-reinitpricing.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("the cron job is running");

        $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
            ->addStoreFilter(1)
            ->load();

            foreach ($collection AS $customer) {
                $logger->info($customer->getId());
    }
}
```

**File: Vendor/Module/etc/crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="vendor_module_price_reinit" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Reinitpricing" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 */6 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: I had already tried this first and it was failing as if it didnt know what customerFactory was

Comment: Check now I have updated answer

Comment: Nothings changed?